# Convolution with autoregressive filter

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive

I am trying to understand what was done with timeseries from one paper.It says

```
The raw time series are prewhitened, typically by convolution with an autoregressive
filter, to reduce the spectral dynamic range. The autoregressive filter must be
computed robustly;
```

I have my ts `x`,how to perform convolution with autoregressive filter in R?Could library forecast be used or...?

**EDIT**
What I have done so far

```
d <- scan('262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_128H.dat')
dts <- ts(d,frequency=32)

png("n1.png")
plot.ts(dts)
dev.off()
```

Then I have plot 
[image]

If I perform two-time differencing

```
d <- scan('262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_128H.dat')
dts <- ts(d,frequency=32)
dts1 <- diff(dts, differences=2)

png("n2.png")
plot.ts(dts1)
```

Then my plot looks like this
[image]

Should I preprocess the data again or not before I start building ARIMA models?

Comment: I would probably adjust/modify/change the data points that are creating the visually unusual values in your first graph.

Comment: @IrishStat But how to do this?

Comment: I would replace each exceptional value with a local average (excluding the unusual value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify an ARIMA filter while taking account (robust) any deterministic time trends, level shifts, seasonal pulses or 1 time anomalies. The idea here is transform the stationary X into a white-noise series. This same filter will then be used on the stationary Y series. The subsequent cross-correlation analysis between these two filtered series yields clues to the form of the transfer between the original X and the original Y. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025004937/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75) for more.

Comment: Please,take a look of my edit.